# What went wrong with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a specific regular expression, `\Good .+\.\`. To my understanding that means, *match each pattern that starts with "Good ", then any number of word characters (one or more) and finally end with a dot ('.')*.

So "Good morning." could is a pattern that this regex is matching, also "Good afternoon.", "Good day.", etc. But somehow it also matches the pattern "Good morning. Good afternoon. Good day." **as a whole**.

How is this possible?

Comment: You need to make the `.+` lazy by adding a `?` i.e. `.+?` otherwise it absorbs all characters (including `.`)  up to the final `.`. Alternatively use, `[^.]+` to only match non-`.` characters

Comment: To answer the first comment @Nick I am not sure if it answers my question since I am learning them at the momment.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Maybe I should have asked differently, like what regex matches the pattern `"Good <any word character>."`. the `<` and `>` are not included in the pattern of course.

Comment: Perhaps `Good\s[a-zA-Z]+\.` or if you use the `i` (case-insensitive) flag `good\s[a-z]+\.`?

Comment: By the way I think you're right, `.+` absorbs the final `\.`.

Comment: You're right, if you could provide an answer so I could mark it as correct apart from thanking you @Nick

Comment: One of the regex gold badge holders will eventually close this as a dupe so no point answering. Thanks are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick noted, `.+` absorbs the final `\.`. I believe it's an example of a *greedy expression* where an expression tries to match the longest possible string.